# Rerouting traffic from OpenVPN client for local-only access

Tags: iptables, routing, openvpn, ufw

I have installed OpenVPN on my server on which I also run git and web server. My initial idea before I got into installing was to be able to enable visiting of some websites only to VPN clients and to allow access to git's SSH only to them. I thought that I will only allow access to ports from VPS's local IPs - 10.254.1.0/24, but I figured out that package seems to be forwarded with my actual IP, not the IP from VPN. My current rule for prerouting from tun interface (I'm using UFW and this is part of iptables' rule which resides in ufw's before.rules):

```
*nat
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.254.1.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
```

I don't quite understand why is client's actual IP assigned to the packet which is sent through VPN, I would rather expect that this packet would be sent from VPN's network. I was thinking about solution for this and the only idea I got was to install OpenVPN on my second server and connect from it. However, the reason I posted this question is that I would more prefer to do this from current server where I already have OpenVPN installed. Any suggestion is welcomed.

Comment: What's the routing table on the vpn client?

Comment: I don't have any special rules for routing in OpenVPN configs, except the `push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"` `push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"` `push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.4.4"` (which are in server config). Routing table from client is here: http://pastebin.com/CK0zDHWU

Comment: Can you try to use this masquerading rule instead? `-A POSTROUTING -s 10.254.1.0/24 -o eth0 ! -d <server-ip> -j MASQUERADE`

Comment: I don't see a static route for the vpn server there, does client-server communication within the tunnel work? Also on the server is eth0 the interface to the rest of the world?

Comment: Client-server communication within tunnel work, server is also available through 10.254.1.1, but it also doesn't accept connection if I try to connect to its VPN IP instead of domain. eth0 is the interface to the rest of the world, yes.

Comment: @maxf: It works but only in case that I try to access directly to 10.254.1.1; Is there any option to override my domain and subdomains with this address (instead of public IP) in OpenVPN config?

Comment: I was thinking to use another rule like this: `-A POSTROUTING -s 10.254.1.0/24 -d <public-server-ip-address> -j DNAT --to-destination 10.254.1.1` but it doesn't work...

Comment: Wait, are you trying to access the vpn server's public IP address through the tunnel instead of directly? Is that the problem you're trying to solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume<sup>*</sup> you're trying to reach the vpn server at it's public address and expecting this connection goes through the tunnel.

This won't happen, your client needs to connect to your vpn server over the public network to establish and maintain the tunnel.

You have several options, the simpler of which seems to be to setup a sort of split-horizon DNS using Dnsmasq.

1. Install Dnsmasq on the server
2. Set a `/etc/hosts` entry pointing your server's name to the vpn address
3. Instead of pushing `DNS 8.8.8.8` for the clients push `DNS 10.254.1.1`

That way your clients will resolve you server name internally while they're connected to the vpn.

If you want the server itself to keep resolving its own name to the public address use an additional hosts file for Dnsmasq instead of the system-wide one at `/etc/hosts`.

---

<sub>*****: if the assumption is wrong the whole answer is useless so please let me know :-)</sub>

Comment: I didn't try this yet, but I think you are correct. Currently if I ping my domain from VPN client, this ping will seems to travel through eth0 and then reach its destination (as actual IP address). If I ping 10.254.1.1 then the server seems to be pinged directly. I suppose this because ping to 10.254.1.1 response in around 100 ms less. Just a question regarding the hosts file - if I just add `10.254.1.1 mydomain.tld sub.mydomain.tld` this should not have any impact on my services? I think that problem could be because there is already an entry for `127.0.0.1 mydomain.tld` ...

Comment: @user1257255 it shouldn't cause any trouble. If it does you can use a separate hosts file as mentioned.

Comment: Last question before I accept answer is about the same thing I asked before. I'm using Ubuntu Server 16.04 and in `/etc/hosts` there already is:
`127.0.0.1 localhost.localdomain localhost
# Auto-generated hostname. Please do not remove this comment.
<actual-ip-address> mydomain.tld  mydomain`
In case that I append `10.254.1.1 mydomain.tld sub.mydomain.tld`, `sub.mydomain.tld` is correctly pointing to 10.254.1.1 meanwhile `mydomain.tld` is pointing to actual server address. Is there an option to also override this one and could this cause any trouble because this entry is generated by OS?

Comment: @user1257255 replacing it shouldn't cause any trouble, it's only visible to the server itself (which can always reach the vpn interface) and the clients when they're connected (can reach the interface). In some situations it can cause trouble for MTAs, but if that's the case it's easy to solve with an additional hosts file specific to Dnsmasq.

Comment: Thank you very much! I created separate hosts file and now everything works as expected.